# NullPointerException thrown from addToBack method from custom LinkedList Array

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to implement a LinkedList. The methods are functioning perfect on this example:

```
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    Node newNode = new Node("sarah", 20);
    list.addToBack(newNode);
    System.out.println(list.nodeAt(0).getName());
```

But not on this example, when I try to use the same method with an array:

```
    LinkedList[] list = new LinkedList[3];
    Node newNode = new Node("sarah", 20);
    list[1].addToBack(newNode);
    System.out.println(list[1].nodeAt(0).getName());
```

For the last example I get the following:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

It's the line where addToBack method is called.
This is the method:

```
public void addToBack(Node newNode) throws NullPointerException {
    if (this.head == null){
        this.head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node current = this.head;
    while (current.hasNext()){
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = newNode;
    ++size;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, but something like that actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create the objects. You just created an array of LinkedList s

```
LinkedList[] lists = new LinkedList[3]; // Just create the array of linked lists
```

You must add thing like this

```
 lists[1] = new LinkedList(); // Create the object at index 1 of the array

 ...


 lists[1].addToBack(newNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your array of LinkedList() objects those indices are all empty. They don't actually contain LinkedLists until you assign them.

```
list[1] = new LinkedList();
//then you can add objects to it
Node newNode = new Node("sarah", 20);
list[1].addToBack(newNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing:

```
LinkedList[] list = new LinkedList[3];
```

You say that list will contain 3 `LinkedList`s, that's it. You **declare** what type of objects `list` will contain, but you don't reserve any place in memory for them. You need to **initialize** this list with `LinkedList`s to perform any operations on them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     list[i] = new LinkedList();
}
```

Now you can call methods making changes in `list` contents.

*By the way, I strongly suggest not to name your own implementations with names that are contained in official Java packages, as it make lot of additional and unnecessary work to you or others reading your code as at most they expect  official `java.util.LinkedList` when looking at code containing `LinkedList`.*